# window.ethereum.request not working on mobile device

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, ethereum, web3js

Expect behavior:

real mobile device

click the `MetaMask` button will trigger the MetaMask APP and login, just like PloyMarket website.

https://polymarket.com/

Actual behavior:

I try to use the function on React project

```
window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });
```

not working on mobile browser

I can understand that because mobile browser doesn't support extension.

I check PolyMarket website behavior it looks like go the specific link, then detect login from APP.

iOS is `https://apps.apple.com/us/app/metamask-blockchain-wallet/id1438144202`

Android is `https://metamask.app.link/dapp/polymarket.com/`

I try do the same thing and test on my iOS device, go to iOS link and open MetaMask APP, it can't detect login from APP.

How can I do the behavior like PolyMarket they do ?

Comment: It is not completely clear on the workflow for you use case, I believe you are describing from Mobile Safari or Mobile Chrome user clicks a link which does X on a on-device installed app. Check: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links and https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Comment: But if open the app from link, web and app are not connected to each other.

Comment: I just found the solution, I need to install MetaMask SDK in my project `https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/connect/set-up-sdk/javascript/react/` and add the MetaMaskProvider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`windows.ethereum` is only available is a web browser has in-browser wallet. It can be built-in (Opera) or extension (desktop MetaMask).

For mobile wallets you need to use [WalletConnect](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-to-your-dapp-and-different-ethereum-wallet-types/82532#82532). [See also other options to connect an Ethereum wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-to-your-dapp-and-different-ethereum-wallet-types/82532#82532).